# meu objetivo é criar um modal de uma imagem no qual recebo no parametro da funcao , ao executar o codigo recebo o erro que minha funcao não existe

Tags: javascript, css, html5

aqui o botao passa o valor pra funcao janelaModal
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

aqyu eu crio as tags com os seus ids
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

aqui estou estilizando as tags atraves dos ids e atribuindo o display:none ao id modal
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

recupero os ids atribuindo o valor que recebo da funcao ao src da minha imagem
e passo o display do modal para  block
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas)

Comment: Você tem certeza que a função existe ? coloca a função no console do navegador, se o action do seu btn funcionar é porq você ta colocando no lugar errado

Comment: Olá, poderia colocar o seu código dentro da pergunta, de forma textual? Não é necessário remover a imagem, mas é importante ter as partes essenciais do seu código fonte no corpo da pergunta. Aprenda porque não é legal colocar imagens em perguntas [Postar mensagem de erro como imagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/7817/103217). Um dos motivos é que se alguém quiser responder a pergunta, não pode copiar e executar o seu código. Imagens não desempenham bem nos mecanismos de busca pelo fato do conteúdo não poder ser indexado.

Answer (score 0):

Boa Noite, mas vc não está passando a função no button. É como se estivesse passando uma string, para passar a função tu tem que colocar em chaves.

```
<button onClick={ () => JanelaModal('url da imagem') }>Ver Certificado</button>
```

Necessita de uma callback para chamar a função. Agora uma pergunta, vc está usando React ?

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).